# Developing a web application for Azure market place

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

I am very new to Azure and Azure market place apps.

I could not find any samples in the Web to create an web application in azure market place. I want to create simple web application then i can publish this in Azure market place. For example, this web application simply retrieves all the users in a SQL table  and show the list in a html page.

I tried different solutions in web and also here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg607768.aspx. But could not able to succeed.

I am confused on how to start developing the market place apps. I mean which project template i should use to develop an Market place App.

Can any one please help me how to start developing the web application for Azure market place?

Answer (score 1):

You may check the process outlined in this document [Publish and manage an offer in the Azure Marketplace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace-publishing/marketplace-publishing-getting-started) - this article is provided to help - create, deploy, and manage solutions listed in the Azure Marketplace. 
Refer to the [Marketplace Publisher Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/marketplace/marketplace-publishers-guide) and [Azure managed applications in the Marketplace](http://Azure%20managed%20applications%20in%20the%20Marketplace) for details.

Publish a Solution Template: Based on your requirement, you could use the solution templates which allows you to combine multiple items already available in the marketplace to create more powerful solutions.

Whereas, the ‘Publish a Developer Service’ provides fully managed developer services (SAAS) for developers to use in custom application development.

Note: Solutions Template has migrated to the new [Cloud Partner Portal](https://cloudpartner.azure.com/) (requires registration prior to access).

Additionally, check the Marketplace FAQs ([here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/faq/)): Who do I contact with publishing or offer management questions? : Please visit the Azure Marketplace Publisher Guide for up-to-date resource and documentations on frequently asked questions. Additionally, you can log a ticket with Microsoft Support in the [Cloud Partner Portal](https://cloudpartner.azure.com/).